# Prove that if $P(A) = P(B) = \frac23$ , then $P(A|B) ≥ \frac12$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Prove that if $P(A) = P(B) = \dfrac23$ , then $P(A|B) ≥ \dfrac12$.

Well I thought that because $P(A) + P(B)> 0$, then they are independent. So I used $P(A|B)= P(A)$ which I can use due to independence. However I have doubts because to be independent they don't necessarily have to be bigger than $0$ but I see no other reason or way to prove that that given probability is bigger than $1/2$.

Comment: Recall the **definition** of $P(A\mid B)$.

Comment: "because P(A) + P(B)> 0, then they are independent" There **must** be something in your notes showing that this deduction of yours is off the mark.

Comment: Suppose you throw a fair die. Let A be the event 4 or fewer pips show and B be the event 3 or more pips show.  Analyze this.

Comment: Well the definition is the P(intersection of A and B)/ P(B)

Comment: @Did I know my assumption is wrong but I don't know another way to explain why the probability would be smaller than a half.

Comment: @ncmathsadist well let's say P(A) is denoted as the probability of getting 4 or smaller and P(B) as getting 3 or more. P(A) = 1/2, P(B) = 1/2, P(intersection) = 1/4 = P(A)* P(B) therefore proving their independence.

Comment: Before "your assumptions", you have a problem with the definitions -- namely, that you do not know them.

Comment: @Did There is nothing given about the intersection so I still don't know whether assuming that they are independent is correct without giving any explanation because it's a 6 mark question.

Comment: Assuming they are independent is definitely incorrect. And unneeded to solve this.

Comment: The statement is false, since we could have $P(A|B) = 1/2$. Surely the problem must be to prove $P(A|B) \ge 1/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Here are the relations which you should use

- $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$
- $P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)\cdot P(B)$
- $P(A\cup B)\leq 1$

All it is left is to put them together.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot.

Comment: @Mewow You´re welcome. I am glad that it helps.

Answer (score -1):

We have P(A) = P(B) = 2/3.

Take P(A|B) and P(A|not B).

We know that P(A) = P(B) * P (A|B) + P(not B) * P(A|not B).

2/3 = 2/3 * P(A|B) + 1/3 * P(A|not B)

We have 0 ≤ P (A|not B) ≤ 1. Therefore

2/3 * P(A|B) + 1/3 * 0 ≤ 2/3 ≤ 2/3 * P(A|B) + 1/3 * 1

P(A|B) ≤ 1 ≤ P(A|B) + 0.5

0.5 ≤ P(A|B) ≤ 1.

(Intuitively: In 2/3rds of all cases we have B, in 1/3rd we have not B. If we don't have A in at least half the cases where B, the numbers of cases with A don't add up to 2/3rds, even if we have A in *all* cases where not B. )

Comment: I'm wondering how you got 6K reputation posting answers without mathjax.